# reading large datadumps with Eclipse-Jena

Tags: java, eclipse, rdf, jena

For my semantic web project I am trying to load huge datasets into my application which I built with eclipse-jena.

Files up to 2gb size with 8 million triplets are working fine. However I am trying 6gb size files now and even for this moderate size the application yields no results (nothing happened after 15 min of waiting)
I am basically using jena's model.read(filepath) method to read the files, and then break them into sujects predicates and objects into json files to be used later.

Any help to overcome this problem or improve performance will be highly appreciated.
Kind regards

**CODE:**

```
        Map<String, Object> classMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        String data = request.getParameter("txtDataSource");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("dataSource", data);   
        model.read(data);
        StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements();
        Resource subject;
        Property predicate;
        RDFNode object;
        int i = 0;
        JSONObject subJson = new JSONObject();   
        JSONObject predJson = new JSONObject(); 
        JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject(); 

        JSONArray objArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray predArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray subjArray = new JSONArray();
        Set<String> usedObjKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> usedSubjKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> usedPredKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Map<String,String>objMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Map<String,String>predMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Map<String,String>subjMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
            subject = stmt.getSubject();
            predicate = stmt.getPredicate();
            object = stmt.getObject();
            String subjKey, predKey, objKey;
            subjKey = subject.getLocalName();
            predKey=predicate.getLocalName();

//          subjectMap.put(subject.getLocalName(),"<"+subject.getURI()+">" );
//          predicateMap.put(predicate.getLocalName(),(predicate.isLiteral() ? predicate.getLocalName() : "<"+predicate.getURI()+">"));
            subjMap.put("key", subject.getLocalName());
            subjMap.put("value",subject.getURI());
            predMap.put("key", predicate.getLocalName());
            predMap.put("value",(predicate.isLiteral() ? predicate.getLocalName() : "<"+predicate.getURI()+">"));

            if(object.isResource())
            {
                objKey = object.asResource().getLocalName();
//              objectMap.put(object.asResource().getLocalName(), "<"+object.asResource().getURI()+">");
                objMap.put("key", object.asResource().getLocalName());
                objMap.put("value", "<"+object.asResource().getURI()+">");
            }
            else{
                objKey = object.toString(); 
//              objectMap.put(object.toString(), object.toString());
                objMap.put("key", object.toString());
                objMap.put("value", object.toString());
            }
            i++;
            System.out.println(i);
            if(!usedObjKeys.contains(objKey))
            {
                usedObjKeys.add(objKey);
                objArray.add(objMap);
            }
            if(!usedSubjKeys.contains(subjKey))
            {
                usedSubjKeys.add(subjKey);
                subjArray.add(subjMap);
            }
            if(!usedPredKeys.contains(predKey))
            {
                usedPredKeys.add(predKey);
                predArray.add(predMap);
            }
        }

        usedPredKeys = null;
        usedSubjKeys = null;
        usedObjKeys = null;
        objJson.put("objects", objArray);
        subJson.put("subjects", subjArray);
        predJson.put("predicates",predArray);

        ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
        String contextPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/data");
        System.out.println(contextPath);
        File dir = new File(contextPath);
        System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());

        File subjectFile = File.createTempFile("subjects", ".json", dir); 
        File predicateFile = File.createTempFile("predicates", ".json", dir); 
        File objectFile = File.createTempFile("objects", ".json", dir); 

        FileWriter fileSubject = new FileWriter(subjectFile.getAbsolutePath());
        FileWriter filePredicate = new FileWriter(predicateFile.getAbsolutePath());
        FileWriter fileObject = new FileWriter(objectFile.getAbsolutePath());


        fileSubject.write(subJson.toJSONString());
        filePredicate.write(predJson.toJSONString());
        fileObject.write(objJson.toJSONString());

        subJson = null;
        predJson= null;
        objJson = null;

        fileSubject.flush();
        fileSubject.close();
        filePredicate.flush();
        filePredicate.close();
        fileObject.flush();
        fileObject.close();
        subjectFile.deleteOnExit();
        predicateFile.deleteOnExit();
        objectFile.deleteOnExit();
```

Comment: It is very hard to debug the runtime behavior of code by just looking at it. Instead of "code improvements by looking"; you should turn to a profiler to collect resilient data. Then decide which pieces of code need to improved. And for starters; did you try to run with increased heap size?

Comment: It would be better to read (once) the data into a local TDB database.

Comment: @Jägermeister simply the read part. I would just post that part but thought there could be sth else that causes performance issues.

Comment: @AndyS how is it different than model.read ?

Comment: `model.read()` reads into JVM heap memory, TDB is a persistent disk backed database for RDF that uses memory-mapped files

Comment: I found the following example yet it doesn't take a file source, only a directory name is provided to be used for the dataset. How can I read a file into tdb dataset ?
 // Make a TDB-backed dataset
  String directory = "MyDatabases/Dataset1" ;
  Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory) ;
  ...
  dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ) ;
  // Get model inside the transaction
  Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel() ;
  dataset.end() ;
  ... 
  dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE) ;
  model = dataset.getDefaultModel() ;
  dataset.end() ;